# Flatlist issue on scrollToIndex

Tags: javascript, react-native

With scrollToIndex, if my element is at the bottom of the list, it scrolls to top leaving the blank space.
anybody faced on this?

[image: ScrollToIndex leave bottom blank space]

Comment: post your code and what you've tried and others will gladly help

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of the mentioned flatlist properties to achieve your goal.

```
[initialScrollIndex]
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#initialscrollindex

```
[initialNumToRender]
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender

You can also implement getItemLayout for performance also https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout

Comment: thanks, but I made some tricks and variuos round dance to the code to calculate the right index to go to top.
here the code i used:
`let lista = this.state.list;
let myIndex = this.findIndex(lista,'id',showId);//here i get the index clicked
let maxI = global.isIphoneX() ? 4:global.isIpad()? 4:2;//here get how many items will be showed based on screens, is not accurate
if(myIndex && myIndex > -1)
  this.listaShow.scrollToIndex({animated:true,index:myIndex,viewOffset:10})
else
  this.listaShow.scrollToEnd({animated:true})`